# Hosting sites for Facebook Application on web

Tags: facebook, web-hosting

I am building a facebook application, and I am facing a problem while configuring the "Canvas URL" & "Secure Canvas URL" on the App-on-Facebook settings.

This needs a web URL with https enablement. I created a sample site on "https://sites.google.com/site" and my url is https://sites.google.com/site/my-site
However, when I use this site as Canvas URL & save, it gives me a weird error --

Error
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.

What could be the possible issue. I am able to post the same site in facebook feeds.

Regards,
Raghav